# Using multiple processors on Solr

Tags: solr

We have 8 cores on the CPU and we have a very inefficient query, which we are fixing. Basically when we reach 1/8th of CPU % Solr falls over.

We should get the query fixed, which will solve our immediate problem, but what happens when we end up with thousands of users simultaneously, even with an efficient query? How do we get Solr to use all the processing capability on the CPU?

The query does involve 2-3 facets. If we set facet.threads to 2 or 3, then it will use more CPU's?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Each Solr request is handled by its own thread and is (nearly) single-threaded all the way for that request. The exception being faceting, where you can increase the number of threads.

When multiple concurrent requests are issued, they will each run in their own thread; with your 8 CPU-core machine, that means that 8 concurrent requests will have all 8 CPU-cores running.

Comment: Thanks @Toke. Shortening the query only partially helped. When we refresh one lister page it takes 3 seconds. When we create 10 lister pages in 3 seconds, the site falls over. Our developers are fishing around but I think the problem is too low level for them. They claim to have it working on their dev machines, but it doesn't work in live. So they must not have the config set correct, either on Solr, or on the ecomm app that calls solr (they are on the same machine in dev, and different servers in live).  Any thoughts, or config examples to set? Much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, the ecomm application is hybris. I just can't believe that we should be falling over with 10 concurrent queries, even if they are a little large?

Comment: It is hard to answer questions about query performance, without knowing what the queries are. Some common culprits are grouping, high cardinality faceting and rows=millions, but I advice that you try the IRC channel (#solr on freenode) as it often takes a lot of interaction to pinpoint such problems.

Of course you could also try the mailing list or post your query question here. If you do so, try to include log-lines containing the full queries and the response times. Also briefly describe the hardware and index size in document count and bytes.

Comment: Thanks, will check out IRC. There is no question that the query is the major issue... it is 22k characters long. with 80 OR statements of the form {catalogue = 1 and facetA=Y and facetB=Z and (facetC=X OR facetD=Y or facetE=Z} OR {catalogue = 2 and facetA=Y and facetB=Z and (facetC=X OR facetD=Y or facetE=Z} (repeat for catalogue 1 to 80) . I assume that this is likely too much for Solr?      The error we actually get is "No live SolrServers available to handle this request"